# Как исключить номера телефонов, содержащие более 4х подряд одних и тех же цифр

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Уже пол часа бьюсь над выражением.

Суть в том, чтобы исключить номера телефонов, содержащие более 4х подряд включений одних и тех же цифр, т.е.:

893700000000
893777777777

и так далее. Все это дело должно работать в Java, пробую matches("7{4,}") для примера 893777777777, на выходе получаю false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String number = "89371477777"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("1{4,}|2{4,}|3{4,},|4{4,}|5{4,}|6{4,}|7{4,}"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(number); 
if (m.find()) { 
    System.out.println("Найдено"); 
}
```

Comment: Было бы лучше если бы ты кусок кода привел

Comment: @G1yyK это будет 4 любых цифры, а не одинаковых.

Comment: упс, чет сразу не допер

Comment: 1{4,}|2{4,}|3{4,}....

Comment: String number = "89371477777";
Pattern.compile("1{4,}|2{4,}|3{4,},|4{4,}|5{4,}|6{4,}|7{4,}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(number);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        System.out.println(b);

Comment: String number = "89371477777";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("1{4,}|2{4,}|3{4,},|4{4,}|5{4,}|6{4,}|7{4,}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(number);
       if (m.find()) {
           System.out.println("Найдено");
       }

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Comment: "Быдлокод" @vladd правильнее советует.

Comment: > ... **|3{4,},|** ...

тут случаем не опечатка?

Answer (score 5):

Можно [проще](http://ideone.com/sjv9NE):

```
(\d)\1{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть более простой вариант:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})\\1");
if(p.matcher("89371477777").find()) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Не совсем: http://ideone.com/9hCuxM

Comment: о таких парах не подумал, спасибо!